# Monitoring operations on HDD on Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, monitoring

I want to monitor operations on HDD in Linux. I tried *iotop*, but I want to know which file is being modified. Is there any tool to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The utility `lsof` should give you a list of all open files on your system.